# How to get all ldetails of the list of specific user's group and description using powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I managed to get the list of  list of specific user's group and description using below script

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership %username%| Get-ADGroup -Properties * | select name, description

However it is not displayed a list of full details and almost all groups and descriptions ended up with .... like below but I need to get full details.

```
SFO-GF-XXXXXXX-SERVICES1-YYYY-C                                            
SFO-GF-XXXXXXX-SERVICES2-WWWWWW...                                        
XXX-GF-N-DATA-FIN-YYY-00MWWWMFIN-2... Read-only access to N:\DATA\XXXXXX\...
XXX-GF-N-DATA-FIN-YYY-00MWWWMFIN-2... Read-only access to N:\DATA\XXXXXXX\...
XXX-GF-N-DATA-FIN-YYY-00MWWWMFIN-2... Read-only access to N:\DATA\XXXXXXX\...
```

Is there other command to display the list of full details?

Comment: This is working !  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$username = Read-Host 'Please enter Username!'
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username | Get-ADGroup -Properties * | select name, description | fl
```

what is %username% ?  it should be $env:username

Answer (score 0):

Does piping to Format-Table or Format-List help?

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership %username% | Get-ADGroup -Properties * | select name, description | Format-Table
```